# ошибка при создании БД на Андроид

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

Учусь писать приложения под Андроид и столкнулся с проблемой. Написал класс работающий с БД. Вот его код:

```
public class DataBaseAzCard   {
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "azcard.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "groups";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_GROUP = "group";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBGROUP = "subgroup";
    public static final String COLUMN_AMOUNT_CARDS = "amountCards";

    private DataBaseAzCardOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DataBaseAzCard(Context context) {
        openHelper = new DataBaseAzCardOpenHelper(context);
        db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase ();
    }

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SCRIPT = "create table " + TABLE_NAME
            + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME_GROUP
            + " text not null unique, " + COLUMN_NAME_SUBGROUP + " text not null unique, "
            + COLUMN_AMOUNT_CARDS + " integer);";

    private class DataBaseAzCardOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


       public DataBaseAzCardOpenHelper(Context context) {
           super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SCRIPT);

       }

       @Override
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
           onCreate(db);
       }

   }

    public void addGroup(String addNewGroup) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_GROUP, addNewGroup);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Но при попытке создания экземпляра этого класса и последующей записи информации в БД примерно следующим образом выскакивает ошибка:

```
DataBaseAzCard dataBaseAzCard = new DataBaseAzCard;

dataBaseAzCard.addGroup(addNewGroup);
```

Где я ошибаюсь? Ниже привожу лог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас синтаксическая ошибка, она возникает всегда или при добавлении уже существующей группы?

Comment: Спасибо за проявленный интерес к вопросу. Ошибка возникала всегда, но действительно заковырка была в использовании мною в качестве имени столбца зарезервированного sql  слова group

Comment: А почему класс не наследуется от SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: А зачем?.. Это класс работы с базой данной добавление, удаление и т..п. будет в нем.. Если же посмотрите внимательно на код, то увидите, что есть еще внутренний приватный класс, который наследуется от SQLiteOpenHelper.. в этом плане все работает..))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка в запросе создания базы данных. Ключевое слово `group` зарезервировано в Sql. Измените название колонки group на `group_name` например.

Comment: Спасибо, за быстрый и результативный ответ. Действительно при изменении имени колонки group на другое имя ошибка пропала. Появились другие :) но в этом вопросе все стало на свои места.

Comment: @ZigZag если данный ответ является решением Вашего вопроса, отметьте его пожалуйста решением(зеленая галка под цифрой слева от текста ответа).